# List only git tags where specific file was changed

Tags: git

I have a Git repo with two files, `index1.js` and `index2.js`. There are multiple commits with tags and one or both files changed in those commits. I want to list the tags in which only `index1.js` was changed.

I tried this but it returns a decorated output with commit message, Date etc. But I only want tags list.

```
git log -p --name-only --decorate index.js
```

I want an output like this:

```
 1. v1.1
 2. v1.2
 3. v1.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super ugly but it works

```
git log --decorate --tags index.js | grep tag: | awk {'print $4'} | sed -e 's/)$//'
```